# Multiple images on web view are not swipe properly

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, wkwebview

I have a `ViewController` with `WKWebView` and this controller is added on `UIPageViewController`.

If a URL that is loaded on the web view having multiple images gallery (these images are left-right swappable) but if I swipe on an image it changes the controller (open next or the previous controller of `UIPageViewController`)

I want that if images are multiple than on swiping images, change image first if the image is last than change controller.

If there is any solution for this please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for disable swiping of `PageViewController`.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in myPageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
```

When you reached to the last image enable the swiping of `PageViewController`.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in myPageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
            recognizer.enabled = true;
        }
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: but in web view how i will know that it is last image, can i recognise or get control on web view image view?????